# Android Espresso intending not working on android version > 5

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-testing, ui-testing

I have an Espresso UI Test that uses [intending](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/) to stub launching a new activity when a button is clicked.
The below code works perfectly fine on devices with Android version 5.1 and lower but on any device with an android version above that `intending` doesn't seem to work as described in the docs.

```
@Test
public void UnitIshTest() throws Exception {
    Instrumentation.ActivityResult result =
            new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());

    intending(hasComponent(TestingController.class.getName())).respondWith(result);
    onView(withId(R.id.layout_with_button)).perform(click());
}
```

Basically I want to check an intent is fired when a particular button is clicked. But I don't actually want the intent to launch the new Activity.

I've attempted to replace the intending line with: `intending(isInternal()).respondWith(result);` to catch any possible intent also without success.

Any idea how to get the same functionality to work on Android 6 & 7 devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a bug ticket on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38003962) since intending doesn't seem to be working as described in the docs and the destination activity is actually launched on devices with newer versions of android.

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes in you gradle file

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2') {

  exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 }
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.3') {

  exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I already have those in my build.gradle file.